# mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId is giving an empty array when console.logged

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, backend, mongoose-schema

This is my table schema

```
var mongoose=require("mongoose");

var tableSchema=new mongoose.Schema({
  tName:String,
  keys:[
    {
      type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref:"key"
    }
  ],
  fields:[
    {
      type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref:"field"
    }
  ]
})
module.exports=mongoose.model("table",tableSchema);
```

----Key Schema

```
var mongoose=require("mongoose")
 var keySchema=new mongoose.Schema({
   name:[String],
   value:[String]
 })
module.exports=mongoose.model("key",keySchema);
```

---field Schema

```
var mongoose=require("mongoose")

 var fieldSchema=new mongoose.Schema({
   name:[String],
   value:[String]
 })
module.exports=mongoose.model("field",fieldSchema);
```

----How I Pushed into

```
  app.post("/table/:id/value",function(req,res){
      var Key={
        name:req.body.key,
        value:req.body.keyValue
      }
      var Field={
        name:req.body.field,
        value:req.body.fieldValue
      }
      table.findById(req.params.id,function(err,foundTable){
        if(err){
          console.log(err)
        }
        else{
          console.log(foundTable)
          key.create(Key,function(err,createKey){
            foundTable.keys.push(createKey)
            console.log(createKey)
          })
          field.create(Field,function(err,createField){
            foundTable.fields.push(createField)
            console.log(createField)
          })
          foundTable.save();
          console.log(foundTable);
            res.redirect("/table/"+req.params.id)
        }
      })
})
```

ObjectId are not being refernced
[Here is the Image that prints the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IGh3D.png)

How I populated the table

```
app.get("/table/:id",function(req,res){
  table.findById(req.params.id).populate("keys").populate("fields").exec(function(err,foundTable){
    if(err){
      console.log(err)
      res.redirect("/")
    }
    else{
      console.log(foundTable);
      res.render("show",{table:foundTable})
    }
  })
})
```

I Dont know where I had gone wrong,
everything seems to be fine but
the objected is not referenced when printed and
it is not being populated

How it should be printed reference: https://bezkoder.com/mongoose-one-to-one-relationship-example/

**This is an example:**
1st schema

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

    const Customer = mongoose.model(
      "Customer",
      new mongoose.Schema({
        name: String,
        age: Number,
        gender: String
      })
    );

    module.exports = Customer;
```

2nd schema

```
 const mongoose = require("mongoose");

    const Identifier = mongoose.model(
      "Identifier",
      new mongoose.Schema({
        cardCode: String,
        customer: {
          type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
          ref: "Customer"
        }
      })
    );

    module.exports = Identifier;
```

How it should be printed

```
{
   _id : ObjectId("5da000be062dc522eccaedeb"),
   cardCode : "5DA000BC06",
   customer : ObjectId("5da000bc062dc522eccaedea"),
   __v : 0
}
```

How it should be populated

```
 [ { _id: 5da135bf61a1dd3e9c2a6e82,
    cardCode: '5DA135BD61',
    customer:
     { _id: 5da135bd61a1dd3e9c2a6e81,
       name: 'bezkoder',
       age: 29,
       gender: 'male',
       __v: 0 },
    __v: 0 } ]
```

Answer (score 0):

try this .populate([ 'keys', 'fields' ])

Answer (score 0):

The reason why `keys` and `fields` are not inserted is that the `foundTable.save()` will be executed before creating the new `Key` and `Field` documents and push there `_id` to the `foundTable`.

One way to solve the issue is by using `async/await`. You can modify your code as below using async/await

```js
app.post("/table/:id/value", async function (req, res) {

  var Key = {
    name: req.body.key,
    value: req.body.keyValue,
  };

  var Field = {
    name: req.body.field,
    value: req.body.fieldValue,
  };

  try {
    const foundTable = table.findById(req.params.id);

    const createKey = await key.create(Key);

    const createField = await field.create(Field);

    foundTable.keys.push(createKey._id);
    foundTable.fields.push(createField._id);

    await await foundTable.save();

    res.redirect("/table/"+req.params.id)
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    // handle failure here
  }
});
```

This will make sure the `Key` and `Field` are created and `_id` is pushed to `foundTable` before saving the `foundTable`

Regarding the `populate` query. Looks like once you save the `_id` of `Field` and `Key` in `foundTable` your existing query itself should work

Comment: Can you please take a look on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77540162/unable-to-fetch-a-field-from-a-table-in-react/77540481?noredirect=1#comment136699940_77540481