# Unable to fetch a field from a table in React

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, schema

I have two tables **teams** and **roasters**. Rosters table contains six team_ids. The name of the teams respect to those ids presented to the teams table. I need to fetch the team_ids with respect to an user and then need to fetch the team_name from **teams** table corresponding to the team_id.

The schemas are as follows.

**user schema**

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    firstName: String,
    lastName: String,
    username: String,
    password: String
});

const User = mongoose.model("User", UserSchema);

module.exports = User;
```

The team schema

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const TeamSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    team_name: String
    
});

const Team = mongoose.model("Team", TeamSchema);

module.exports = Team;
```

**Rosters schema**

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const TeamRosterSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    team_id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    member_id: [mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId]
});

const Roster = mongoose.model("Roster", TeamRosterSchema);

module.exports = Roster;
```

They are linked in a way the userid of userschem should be matched with the member_id of the roasters schema. Then we get the corresponding team_id. This team_id of the roasters schema should be matched with the team_id of the team schema so that I can get the team name.

I am struggling in matching the team_id of roasters schema with the team_id of team schema so that I get the team name.

Here is my code

```
import React from 'react';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import { Navbar } from './Navbar';

import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

const Home = () => {
  const user_id = localStorage.getItem('loggedInUser');
  
  const [teamNames, setTeamNames] = useState([]); 
  const [userData, setUserData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const userResponse = await axios.get('http://localhost:9000/getUser');
        const userData = userResponse.data;

        const userTeamId = await fetchUserTeamId(user_id);
        **console.log('userTeamId:', userTeamId);**

        setUserData(userData);

        // Fetch and set team names
        const teamNames = await fetchTeamNames(userTeamId);
        setTeamNames(teamNames);
        console.log('teamNames:', teamNames);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
      }
    };

    fetchData();
  }, [user_id]);  

  const fetchUserTeamId = async (userId) => {
    try {
      const rostersResponse = await axios.get('http://localhost:9000/getTeamRoster');
      const userTeamId = rostersResponse.data
        .filter((rosters) => rosters.member_id && rosters.member_id.includes(userId))
        .map((rosters) => rosters.team_id); 

      return userTeamId;
      
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error fetching user team ID:', error);
      return null;
    }
  };

  const fetchTeamNames = async (teamId) => {
    try {
     
     const teamResponse = await axios.get('http://localhost:9000/getTeam');
     console.log('teamResponse.data:', teamResponse.data);
     
     const teamNames  = teamResponse
     
     .filter((team)=> team.team._id === teamId)
     .map((team)=>team.team_name)
     
      return teamNames;
      
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error fetching team names:', error);
      return [];
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="container mt-5">
      <Navbar />
     

      {user_id && (
        <div>
          <label>Hi &nbsp;</label>
          {userData.map((users) => (
            users._id === user_id && <span key={users._id}>{users.firstName} {users.lastName}</span>
          ))}
          <div>
            <label>Your team name:</label>
            <ul>
              {teamNames.map((teamName, index) => (
                <li key={index}>{teamName}</li>
              ))}
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      )}
    
    </div>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

Using the console commands I saw that **console.log('userTeamId:', userTeamId);** return an object id such as **['6539c319a688a6e69c565e3d']**

**console.log('teamResponse.data:', teamResponse.data);** returns all the teams listed under the team tables. The output is

```
0: {_id: '651b3a9c6c50475080d85fc1', team_name: 'Sixth', __v: 0}
1: {_id: '651b4dcd4c5c42a0afd9cdaa', team_name: 'Seventh', __v: 0}
2: {_id: '6539c319a688a6e69c565e3d', team_name: 'First', __v: 0}
3: {_id: '6539c335a688a6e69c565e45', team_name: 'Third', __v: 0}
4: {_id: '6539d2c675f5301e326318ea', team_name: 'Second', __v: 0}
length: 5
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
```

However, teamNames returns an empty array

```
teamNames: []length: 0[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
```

Also there is another error on the

```
console  Home.js:80  Error fetching team names: TypeError: teamResponse.filter is not a function
    at fetchTeamNames (Home.js:72:1)
    at async fetchData (Home.js:40:1)
```

All the http:// links on the code working well.

Backend API

```
app.get('/getTeam', async (req, res) =>{
    const team = await Team.find()
    res.json(team);

})

app.get('/getTeamRoster', async(req, res)=>{
    const TeamRoster = await Roster.find(); 
    res.json(TeamRoster)
}
)
```

Mongodb table for Rosters
[image]

Mongodb table for Teams
[image]

Answer (score 1):

From your console.log('teamResponse.data:', teamResponse.data) it seems that teamResponse.data is an array, so you should use teamResponse.data.filter instead of just teamResponse.filter.

```js
const teamNames = teamResponse.data
 .filter((team) => team._id === teamId) // not team.team._id === teamId
 .map((team) => team.team_name)
```

In your fetchTeamNames function, you are trying to filter teams based on the team ID, but the team ID in your rosters schema is stored as an ObjectId. So, you need to convert the team ID you get from fetchUserTeamId to a MongoDB ObjectId before using it in the filter.

```js
const userTeamId = rostersResponse.data
 .filter((rosters) => rosters.member_id && rosters.member_id.includes(userId))
 .map((rosters) => rosters.team_id.toHexString()) // here convert ObjectId to string
```

Also in your JSX, you are mapping over teamNames, but if it's an empty array, the mapping won't render anything. You might want to add a condition to display a message if there are no team names.

```js
<ul>
  {teamNames.length > 0 ? (
    teamNames.map((teamName, index) => (
      <li key={index}>{teamName}</li>
    ))
  ) : (
    <li>No team found</li>
  )}
</ul>
```

Comment: I still did not get teamname. Previously, userTeamId received some value but now it receives null. In the UI the output is no Team found but I know there is a team for the logged in user.

Comment: sharing the backend API code would be beneficial imo